# What is the geometric interpretation of this quantity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be  a compact $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Using the metric to identify the tangent and cotangent bundles defines a natural symplectic 
structure on the tangent bundle, $(TM, \omega)$, and a natural volume form $\Omega=\omega^{n}$ on $TM$.

For every $r>0$, let $D_{r}(M)$ be the open disc bundle on $M$, with radius $r$. Namely $D_{r}(M)$ is the subset of $TM$ formed by all tangent vectors with length smaller than $r$.

Define:

${C(r)=(\text{Gromov width of $D_{r}(M)$}})^{2n}$

$V(r)$=The Volum  of $D_{r}(M)$ with respect to $\Omega$

Question :

> 1) Does  $\lim_{r\to \infty} C(r)/V(r)$ exist?  And what is its geometric interpretation?
>
> 2) Does   $\lim_{r\to 0} C(r)/V(r)$ exist?    And what is its geometric interpretation?

Recall that the Gromov width of  a symplectic manifold $N$ of dimension 2n defined as follows:

$\sup\; \{\rho \mid \text{there is  a symplectic embedding from $B_{\rho}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ to $N$}\}$.

By $B_{\rho}(0)$  I mean the disc around the origin with radius $\rho$.

Comment: What is the capacity you're referring to? Could you give a reference? Could you also provide some motivation for the question? In particular, why should the exponent be exactly $n$? Finally, have you tried computing any reasonable example (_e.g._ tori, products...)?

Comment: In the revised version I wrote the definition of symplectic capacity. Moreover the true exponent is not $n$ but is $2n$, the dimension of total space. I edited it know

Comment: Thank you for your comment on the "exponent".motivating by $M=S^{1}$,(and $M=\mathbb{T}^{n}$) we observe that the true power must be "2", otherwise the above limit goes to 0 or infinity.

Comment: I apologize for several changing the true exponent. it was because of my miss computation. the true exponent is 2n , because the volume  of a $\rho$-disk in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is of order $\rho^{2n}$. On the other hand a symplectic embedding preserve the volume

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both limits (1) and (2) are equal to $C(1)/V(1)$ because of the homogeneity of the volume and the symplectic capacity. Namely, the symplectic form is homogeneous of degree $1$ with respect to dilations on the tangent bundle and so it makes no difference what the radius of your disc bundle is.

What is then geometric meaning of $C(1)/V(1)$ ? That's an interesting and difficult question which falls under the topic of capacity-volume inequalities (something that is just taking off). I'd suggest looking at flat tori first. The reason is that if you consider the universal cover, the lattice, and the ellipsoid that defines your unit disc, then if you have a lattice basis inside the ellipsoid, you also have a symplectic unit ball inside the unit tangent bundle of your torus : just look at the moment map of the torus action on the unit ball: it's image is (or can be made to be) the simplex formed by the origin and your lattice basis. You will probably be able to give a number-geometric interpretation to $C(1)/V(1)$ in this case.

By the way, **the** original capacity-volume problem is

**The Viterbo Conjecture.** *The symplectic capacity (any capacity!) of a convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ whose volume is the same as that of the $2n$-dimensional Euclidean unit ball is less than or equal to $\pi$.*

Note that this is obviously true for the Gromov width, but it is open for every other capacity. There is a chance this conjecture is true for the Hofer-Zehnder capacity, which can be more easily described as the least of the actions of all closed characteristics on the boundary of $K$. There are some partial results on this conjecture in the **first version** of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4253), but beware, by a recent [result](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4197) of Artstein-Avidan, Ostrover, and Karasev, a positive answer to Viterbo's conjecture would also prove the Mahler conjecture (corollary: this can't be easy!).

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer. I apologize if my question is elementary; is it obvious that the capacity is homogeneous of order 1? assuming this, what is the  the true exponent in  definition of $C(r)$, $n$ or $2n$, because $V(r)$ is  probably of order $n$(and what is reason for this last statement?)

Comment: $V(r)$ has order $n$: when you dilate in the tangent bundle you only dilate in the direction of the velocities (half the dimension of the total space). Every capacity satisfies $c(M, \lambda \omega) = \lambda c(M, \omega)$ for $\lambda > 0$ (and, yes, this is basically immediate for Gromov width). Since dilation in the velocities dilates the symplectic form, you need to use the exponent $n$ on both the capacity and the volume so that the question be meaningful.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, could you please introduce me a reference with minimum necessary background?

Comment: The "classic" text is McDuff, Salamon "Introduction to symplectic topology".

Comment: the $\lambda$ in your comment is a constant. But I do not understand the relation to computation of capacity of $D_{r}(M)$. Perhaps I do not underestand a simple fact, I would appreciate if you explain.

Comment: How much do you know of symplectic geometry (from where should I explain)?

Comment: I know only the basic definitions

Comment: I don't want to sound mean spirited, but posting questions which should be research level and knowing only the basic definitions may not lead to interesting exchanges. Pick up McDuff and Salamon, it's a great book.

Comment: I  agree with your  comment and  my +1 for that. But  I  am  just  curious in the following question(Sorry, if  it is  elementary, to be honest , for the moment I  have  no  access to  the book of McDuff)  Is there a  concept of  Contact  capacity, the  biggest  disk in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$  with its  standard  contact  structure,   which  can  be  contactly  embeded  in a  given contact  manifold?